# Change Jquery Slider Initial Value to Word

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have built a rating form am using a JQuery UI increment slider except my values are words not numbers. However, the initial value is still shows up as a number. I have tried changing `value="0"` to `value="Not Yet Rated"` but this ends up breaking the slider.

Any and All help is appreciated.

```
<html>

<div class="kpa_rate kpa_rate1">
    <label for="kpa1_rating_value">Parking:</label>

    <div id="1" class="slider"></div>
    <input type="text" class="kpa1_rating_value" name="kpa1_rating" value="0" />       
</div>




<div class="kpa_rate kpa_rate2">
    <label for="kpa2_rating_value">Entrance:</label>

    <div id="2" class="slider"></div>
    <input type="text" class="kpa2_rating_value" name="kpa2_rating" value="0" />
</div>



</html>
```

JavaScript

```
    <script>
$(function() {
    var Array = ["Poor Accesibility","Okay Accessibility", "Moderate Accessibility", "Good Accessibility","Great Accessibility"];
                $( ".slider" ).slider({
                  range: "max",
                  min: 0,
                  max: 4,
                  value: $("input", this).val(),
                  slide: function( event, ui ) {                    
                    //get the id of this slider
                    var id = $(this).attr("id");
                    //select the input box that has the same id as the slider within it and set it's value to the current slider value. 

$("input[class*=" + id + "]").val(Array[ui.value]);
                  }
                });
              });
</script>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just set the input's initial value from `value="0"` to `value="Poor Accesibility"`? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Vpy3c/

Comment: This was actually my first solution and it doesn't work? Works in JSFiddle fine. However, when I add it to the form and test it in a browser the slider no longer works.

Comment: If it works in the fiddle but not in your page, then there's other code causing the issue that isn't represented here. Check your console for errors?

Comment: I keep trying. Even uploaded it to the web. [Take a Look Here](http://survey.patrickbickham.com/). Funny thing is it works when I make sure the first one has a #, [See Here](http://survey.patrickbickham.com/index_1.html)

Comment: Seems like `value: $("input", this).val(),` doesn't exist in your actual code. Try `value: $(this).parent().next().next().find('input').val(),`

Comment: AMAZING! Thank you very much. Can't wait to learn JavaScript. Much Appreciated, works great!

Comment: I'll post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `value: $("input", this).val(),` doesn't exist in your actual code.

Try value: `$(this).parent().next().next().find('input').val(),`